# Sending Table as a List into List<Model.Sublist> Method Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

I am sure this is a duplicate but I can't find an example in the context I am attempting to do this.

I have a list within a model and I have a method that's supposed to take the list; however, when I try to pass in the list from the Front end table I get Count = 0 and it is something silly I am missing.

I want to send the whole table as a list and use `result = await userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, model.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(y => y.RoleName));` to go through and add the models that have isSelected. I am open to other ideas though. I'd just like to avoid javascript if possible

Table:

```html
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="roles" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="roles-tab">
         <form method="post">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <table class="table table-hover table-md" id="roleTable">
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                       <td class="text-left tableHead d-none">RoleId</td>
                       <td class="text-left tableHead">Role</td>
                       <td class="text-right tableHead">Delete</td>
                     </tr>
                  </thead>

           @*--Table Body For Each to pull DB records--*@
                  <tbody>
                     @{int i = 0;}
                       @foreach (var role in Model.Roles)
                       {
                        <tr>
                          <td class="d-none">@role.RoleID</td>
                          <td>@role.RoleName</td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@role.IsSelected" name="checkbox" id="checkbox@(i)" class="float-right center-box" />
                                <label class="form-check-label d-none" asp-for="@role.IsSelected"></label>                                                                   
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                         i++;
                        }
                   </tbody>
              </table>
             </div>
           <button type="submit" asp-action="ManageUserRoles" asp-controller="Administration" asp-route-userid="@Model.Id" class="btn btn-primary padFloat green">Update</button>
           <a asp-action="UserMaint" class="btn btn-primary padFloat blue">Cancel</a>
       </form>
</div>
```

Model:

```c#
namespace PortalDev.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class EditUserViewModel
    {

        public EditUserViewModel()
        {
            Claims = new List<Claim>();
            Roles = new List<Role>();
            CompanyLists = new List<CompanyList>();
        }

        //ROLES ---------------------------------------------
        public class Role
        {
            public string RoleName { get; set; }
            public string RoleID { get; set; }
            public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

        }
        public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

        //CLAIMS----------------------------------------------
        public class Claim
        {
            public string ClaimType { get; set; }
            public string ClaimID { get; set; }
        }
        public List<Claim> Claims { get; set; }

        //User Info---------------------------------------------
        public string Id { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }                                
    }

}
```

Method:

```c#
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ManageUserRoles(List<EditUserViewModel.Role> model, string userid)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userid);

            if (user == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {userid} cannot be found";
                return View("NotFound");
            }

            var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user); 
            var result = await userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cannot remove user existing roles");
                return View(model);
            }

            //Only add roles where "is selected" is true to user's list of roles
            result = await userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user,
                    model.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(y => y.RoleName));

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cannot remove user existing roles");
                return View(model);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("UserMaint");

        }
```

Comment: use the index for the checkbox... ex: @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Roles[i])     Also see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57312680/pass-back-multiple-selected-checkbox-options-using-razor-in-mvc  There are some quirks with bools in asp.net...

Comment: Sometimes it is necessary to put in an additional hidden field set to false for the value.  (If you have a problem where the unchecked entries aren't getting through to the controller, add the hidden field of false... )

Comment: @pcalkins I am a bit confused. I was attempting to use index before like in other parts of our app but it gives me an error. When i Try to use your Html.CheckBoxFor.. example it gives me a convert type error: 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'EditUserViewModel.Role' to 'bool'. Bear with me -- I am an entry level programmer so my ignorance is why I am struggling

Comment: my bad, you need "model => Model.Roles[i].IsSelected"

Comment: you probably also want to include the other fields as hiddens... so @Html.HiddenFor(model=>Model.Roles[i].RoleID)... etc... this would pass the whole "role" back to the controller...

Comment: for convenience you can just bind the List<Role>... that way your method automatically gets it.  (No need pass it into the method...) Use the [BindProperty] tag: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: actually see this link for model binding, it's a little more straight-forward: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

Comment: @pcalkins I attempted your solution -- but I am still getting the same issue where it's not getting the model on the method.

Comment: List your filenames for the .cshtml file and the .cs file.  You may just need to create the method as OnPost...

Comment: cshtml is _EditUserModalPartial.cshtml || 
controller is AdministrationController.cs ||
Model is EditUserViewModel.cs

Comment: confirm that the viewmodel is included in the .cs file.  Also confirm that the method is being hit.  I've never added those routes to the button tag, always to the form tag, so I'm not familiar with this approach.  Seems like they should be in the form tag.

Comment: @pcalkins the view model is included in the controller - I am using the same model for other things. It is hitting the method. But when I check ```List<EditUserViewModel.Role> model``` it has count = 0. On the button - are you suggesting I just put```<input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" /> ```?

Comment: yes, put those asp-... tags in the form tag.  The submit button will run the form action.  And bind the viewmodel... so the method becomes ManageUserRoles()  You won't need asp-route-userid... just include any id in hidden fields in the form.  All data should be in the form and bound to the controller.